# Autocomplete in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

In my rails application I have this field with autocomplete

```
<%= f.label :company_name, class: "profile_label"  %><br />
<%= f.text_field :company_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Company.order(:name).map(&:name) },:autocomplete => :off, class: 'autocomplete-experience form-control profileform-botttom' %>
```

I have also this coffescript file for the autocomplete

```
jQuery ->
  $('.autocomplete-experience').autocomplete
    source: $('.autocomplete-experience').data('autocomplete-source')
    select: (event,ui) -> $("input.xx").val(ui.item.id)
```

This works but only for the first field. When I add another field thought the link to add method the autocomplete won't work for the second field.  why is this and how can I resolve this?

Update

this is the code used to add fields

```
$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

the warning message

```
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' edit:1069:2 Use of
> getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. edit
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' edit:2:2 SyntaxError:
> expected expression, got '<' edit:2:2
```

and this is the code that give this warning

```
  $('#resume-tab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
  });
```

Comment: How do you add the second field? If you add it through javascript you may need to call your autocomplete function again.

Comment: yes i added it through coffeescript you can see the code at the update

Comment: You need to recall `$('.autocomplete-experience').autocomplete` after you created new HTML elements in the page. Add `$('.autocomplete-experience').autocomplete` at the end of the form's 'add fields' `onclick` event and it should deploy autocomplete on the newly added fields.

Comment: @MrYoshiji I have tried your solution but this didn't worked

Comment: do you get any javascript error/warning message? (see your browser's console)

Comment: In my browser console I see this warning SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' edit:1069:4
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. edit
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' edit:2:4
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: Can you post those lines or create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I have added the warning messages in the update

Comment: @rocki I'm sorry I meant the lines that gave the SyntaxError. It should be line 2 of `edit`

Comment: the code that give me this warning is a bootstrap code for tab you can see it in the update

Answer (score 1):

The `$.autocomplete` call will only work for the elements that are alreay in the DOM. After you add a field dynamically you should call `autocomplete` again.

```
setup_autocomplete = ->
  $('.autocomplete-experience').autocomplete
    source: $('.autocomplete-experience').data('autocomplete-source')
    select: (event,ui) -> $("input.xx").val(ui.item.id)

jQuery ->
  setup_autocomplete()

$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
  setup_autocomplete()
```

Comment: I have already tried your solution but didn't succeed to get it working  only the first field that work

Comment: Does your second field has the same class `autocomplete-experience` ?

Comment: yes it is a dynamic field so the second field will have the same class as the first